# jQuery & CSS - Cut text by height, no truncate

Tags: jquery, css, text, hide, toggle

Because I want to toggle my text I need to hide a part of it.

**Problem**

- My text height is going to be X or less pixels in height.
- The height of the div depends on a sidebar height and is not as static as this demo.
- If the letters on the last row are now truncated (se demo), I want to hide that row as well.

**Look at my demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qWDLb/1/

My own thougt would be if the height could be calculated by using line-height or font sizes?

Comment: Links to external sites can be a useful *adjunct* to a question, but always post the relevant code/markup *in the question itself*. More: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: Best bet is to simply set the div's height in ems. Specifically, in multiples of `line-height`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine line-height with:

```
$('.text').css('line-height')
```

This give you this height with 'px' at the end. Here is a working jsfiddle for showing 4 lines : http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/qWDLb/3/ .

Answer (score 0):

You will want to deal with EMs. Figure out the div's height, and if necessary, you can shrink the height of the DIV to hide the partial line.

http://webdev-il.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-convert-pixel-to-em-why-use-ems_31.html